# Compiler does not identify class on the same package

Tags: java

I had some java classes a couple years ago, due to lack of use it all faded away. now ive been getting back into it. i was following a very simple tutorial building something using sublime (it was so simple i didn't bother on getting a proper IDE) the two files are:

```
package hello;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        System.out.println(greeter.sayHello());
        System.out.println("random alt shift");
    }
}
```

and

```
package hello;

public class Greeter {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Greeter compiles dine but HelloWorld gives me the following error:
`javac HelloWorld.java`

```
HelloWorld.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class HelloWorld
2 errors
```

and if i add "import hello.Greeter;" i get:

```
HelloWorld.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
import hello.Greeter;
            ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: package hello
HelloWorld.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class HelloWorld
3 errors
```

On the IDE it runs fine, can anyone be so kind as to explain whats happening

Comment: @SureshAtta No he doesn't. There is no need to explicitly import classes from the same package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

The problem is here. You're in the wrong directory. You should be up one level, where the package hierarchy starts, and you should be issuing

```
javac hello/HelloWorld.java
```

Comment: Worked marvelously, could you explain me why i need to be one level higher?

Comment: Because compilation needs to respect the package structure, and the package is rooted one level higher than you had been telling `javac`, and you didn't use command-line options to make it clear.

Comment: @LewBloch Sorry to revive an old question, but I'm still confused on why we must compile outside of the package hierarchy. What is the point of this?

Comment: You aren't outside the package hierarchy. You're at the top of the hierarchy. The top level is the unnamed package. It's a bad idea to use the unnamed package. Outside the hierarchy would be one more level up.